# Apply KB patch to docker windows server image

Tags: docker

I've started using a docker image based on windows server image `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1909` but I was wondering how do I apply the updates?
On Linux images, I can perform it, but here I don't know the commands

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When using Docker, it's common to not run an update in the container itself, but just replacing the whole container image with an updated one. That's also the way Microsoft suggests in their docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/update-containers.

So you can update the container's image using `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1909` and then run a new container.

Comment: but excuse me, I don't know when a new image is posted...and I've to rebuild my image, since I've installed some software on my current image